# How do I use Gtk.Plug in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, gtk

I'm trying to extend gnome-sushi, which is written using the new GIntrospection-based Javascript bindings.
Now, I'm trying to create a Gtk.Plug object:

```
this._gtkPlug = new Gtk.Plug({ socket_id: xid });
```

However, this just results in

```
JS ERROR: !!!   Exception was: Error: No property socket_id on this GObject GtkPlug
```

I have not found *any* documentation how the GTK objects are mapped to Javascript properties. Can anybody either point me to the correct documentation or tell me how to determine the correct properties?